# How to access RapidAPI text to speech api?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, text-to-speech, rapidapi

https://rapidapi.com/appsplosionhelp/api/ai-text-to-code-generation/

This api doesn't use a /get, but it uses a post, so what would I put in the params to access the api.

```
export const articleApi = createApi({
    reducerPath:'articleApi',
    baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://ai-text-to-code-generation.p.rapidapi.com/',
        prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
            headers.set('X-RapidAPI-Key', 'rapidApiKey');
            headers.set('X-RapidAPI-Host', 'ai-text-to-code-generation.p.rapidapi.com');

            return headers;
        }
    }),
    endpoints:(builder) => ({
        getSummary: builder.query({
            query: (params) => 'Generate Code from Natural Language?url=${encodeURIComponent(params.articleUrl)}&length=3'
        })
    })
});
```